# Ошибка в разделе «Все действия» в профиле

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

В разделе «Все действия» в профиле используется слово *награждений*, хоть оно там и неуместно.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несмотря на задававшийся ранее вопрос, ошибка не была исправлена.
Аналог на enSO:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Осталось найти, где ещё есть этот `awarded-награждений`

Comment: @vp_arth было бы неплохо, наверное

Comment: Вероятно, тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Comment: На мой взгляд, [awarded](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266659?q=key%3A87e8bcb1c1d6264d54bcbe34371c92b5) либо неверно переведено, либо неверно используется вместо [awarded](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/138895775?q=key%3A58f85974b567b37578628981bf79cc27|numAwarded%3Dmany)

Comment: @vp_arth думаю, нужно исправить перевод.

Comment: Вероятно, нет простого способа проверить, нужно исправлять. Исправьте, если изменится и на странице знаков в справке - пойдём чинить выше. `получен знак`, `получен`, `выдан` или что-то вроде того... Я бы туда пустую строку положил)

Comment: @vp_arth увы, не могу этого сделать, поэтому и написал баг-репорт.